# Getting an "invalid literal for int with base 10" in Python

Tags: python, string, int, python-3.4, literals

```
import random
print("Welcome to RNG Guesser!\n")
gld = random.randrange(1,10)
counter = 0
ccounter = 0

while True:
    print("Number of tries: {}".format(counter))
    print("Number of correct guesses: {}".format(ccounter))

num = input("Enter a number: ")

if num is "exit":
    print("Number of tries: {}".format(counter))
    print("Number of correct guesses: {}".format(ccounter))
    break
else:

    if int(num) is gld:
        print("Congratulations, your guessed number {} was right!".format(num))
        counter += 1
        ccounter += 1

    elif int(num) < gld:
        print("Pick a higher number!")
        counter += 1

    else:
        print("Pick a lower number!")
        counter += 1
```

Why am I getting the "invalid literal for int" when I type in exit? I tried converting the input variable to int, I tried with an else statement, I tried making 2 variables, one for string one for int, and none of them worked.

Comment: Operator for comparison is `==`, not `is`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is from the line: 
`if num is "exit"`

Is evaluating to `False` and further down the script when Python tries to convert the literal string `exit` to an int, it will fail.

Try replacing `is` with `==`

The problem is that `is` compares two objects to see if they are the same, whereas what want to is to see if the tow objects' values are the same. Check this [stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the incorrect indentation in the question is just a copy-paste mistake... try this:

```
x = input('enter x > ')
print('x == "exit": {}'.format(x == "exit"))
print('x is "exit": {}'.format(x is "exit"))
```

Here's what happens:

```
enter x > exit
x == "exit": True
x is "exit": False
```

Or maybe:

```
x is "exit": True
```

The `is` operator compares object *identity* but you are trying to compare the contents of two strings.

Comment: Assuming the indentation is correct, his code would be stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: I mean "assuming your indentation is correct, unlike the indentation in the question."  However, it wouldn't be an infinite loop if it were indented like the question--it would be a `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you cannot give a string with non-numeric characters to `int()`.

Now `num` is supposed to be a `str`, and it could be anything from user input. Also note that when you want to evaluate two values, use `==` instead of `is`. `is` is supposed to be used as judging if two things are the same object.

If you want to use if-else, try this:

```
if num == "exit":
    print("Number of tries: {}".format(counter))
    print("Number of correct guesses: {}".format(ccounter))
    break
elif not num or not all(char.isdigit() for char in num):
    print("You are not giving a number.")
else:
    if int(num) == gld:
        print("Congratulations, your guessed number {} was right!".format(num))
        counter += 1
        ccounter += 1

    elif int(num) < gld:
        print("Pick a higher number!")
        counter += 1

    else:
        print("Pick a lower number!")
        counter += 1
```

Here, `all(char.isdigit() for char in num)` is checking for every character in `num` to see if they are all numbers. We should be aware that anything could appear in user's input. Only numbers can be converted to `int`.

We have another solution which is more clear and simple. You may need to read some documents on `try...except...` in Python.

```
try:
    if int(num) ...
except ValueError:
    # num is not able to be converted to int
    print("You are not giving a number.")
```

Comment: The validation `all(char.isdigit() for char is num)` incorrectly accepts empty strings.  Easy way to fix this is to just use `try: ... int(num) ... except ValueError:`

Comment: @DietrichEpp Yes you're right, I wanted to provide the solution using `try...except` but finally sticked to the structure he used. I will edit the answer.